# Learning Swift and Trying to Create a String Loop in a Label

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In Swift I'm trying to loop an array of Strings in a label automatically on a  1-2 second interval.

For example, I have the following Strings in an array:

```
Red
Blue
Green
```

I want the label to scroll through these.

For a better idea, here is what I currently have;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var Label2: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func RandomWord() {
        var RandomWord = arc4random_uniform(5)
        switch (RandomWord) {
        case 0:
            Label.text = "Blue"
            if Label.text == "Blue" {
                Label.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            Label.text = "Red"
            if Label.text == "Red" {
                Label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            Label.text = "Green"
            if Label.text == "Green" {
                Label.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            Label.text = "Yellow"
            if Label.text == "Yellow" {
                Label.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            Label.text = "Orange"
            if Label.text == "Orange" {
                Label.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }

    @IBAction func RandomNumber() {
        var RandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(100)
        Label2.text = String(RandomNumber)
    }

}
```

I want to remove the need for a button and just have the label loop through the strings. Any ideas on the best solution?

Comment: refer this [link](http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/13/swift-tutorial-how-to-use-an-array-in-swift/)

Comment: Is there a way to use arc4random_uniform?

Comment: I updated my question above, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This kind of text scrolling / crawling functionality is not built into `UILabel` automatically.  You could implement it yourself (which wouldn't be the most trivial thing), or you could take advantage of the work that somebody else did in some Open Source project.

For example, I just found [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) which does have a [Swift implementation you can use](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift).

Try adding that to your project and see if that takes care of your need.

Comment: I'm not trying to really have it like a marquee but more just going through the stings. I know that with a button I can activate arc4random_uniform and use a Switch to go through the different strings, I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this automatically without a button?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for something like the following where on a timed interval, a random color is selected an used to populate the text and text color of a label:

```
struct ColorData {
    let name: String
    let value: UIColor
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let data = [
        ColorData( name: "Blue", value: UIColor.blueColor() ),
        ColorData( name: "Red", value: UIColor.redColor() ),
        ColorData( name: "Green", value: UIColor.greenColor() )
    ]

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var timer = NSTimer()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear( animated )

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 1.0, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true )
    }

    func update() {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(self.data.count))
        let colorData = data[ randomIndex ]
        self.label.text = colorData.name
        self.label.textColor = colorData.value
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear( animated )

        // Don't forget to invalidate, otherwise this instance of `MyViewController` will leak
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I believe this is what the OP is *really* looking for.  I was thrown by the use of word "scrolling" in the original edit of the question.  I'll leave my answer in place in case other folks need help with scrolling & crawling.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect!

Comment: Do you mind helping break it down for me on what is occurring? Just so I get a better understanding

Comment: First, I created a custom data type `ColorData` to hold the text and color we will use, and created an array of them.  When the view controller appears, it starts a time that will call the `update()` function every `1.0` seconds.  In `update()`, a `ColorData` object is randomly selected from the array we created, and the `name` and `value` properties are used to set the corresponding properties on our label.  This timer will repeat indefinitely and retain our view controller, so when the view controller disappears we stop the timer and release the memory by calling `invalidate()`.

Comment: No problem.  Would you mind marking this as the correct answer? :)